# Adding an OCX control to a web page Dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net, activex, ocx

I currently have an web based application that hosts an OCX control. I want to be able to add this control programatically if possible allowing me to plug in new OCX controls without having to ammend the OBJECt tag in the HTML.

I also need to be able to maintain the ability to download the OCX control to the Client if it is not found.

Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 0):

You can create the `<object>` tag for the control at run-time by directly manipulating the DOM. This will also let you download the .ocx to the user if he doesn't have it, like any normal `<object>` tag would do.